# Adding multiple items in cart for multiple types of products clicked. Ecom app Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

As of now I have fetched some product data from api and showing it on homescreen. Now I have detailed screen for each product and from detailed screen user can add that product with whatever quantity into cart screen. Now I want to add multiple products with any number of quantity into cart screen and each product is shown on different cards into cart screen.
How can I achieve that? Currently I am able to do it for one product but quantity value is same for all types of products on click.

This is my ProductDetail fragment for each product from where I am adding items and it's quantity to the cart.

```
package com.example.ecomapp.view

import android.app.Application
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.fragment.app.*
import com.example.ecomapp.CartFragment
import com.example.ecomapp.R
import com.example.ecomapp.databinding.FragmentProductDetailBinding
import com.example.ecomapp.viewmodel.MainViewModel
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


class ProductDetailFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var binding: FragmentProductDetailBinding
    //var quantityValue = 0
    private val viewmodel:MainViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       /// return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product_detail, container, false)
        binding = FragmentProductDetailBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        // Log.d("PriceAmount", binding.priceAmount.text.toString())
        Log.d("Price", binding.price.toString())
        Log.d("Title", binding.titleDetail.toString())
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val navBar:BottomNavigationView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation)
       // navBar.visibility = View.GONE


        binding.productDetails1 = arguments?.getParcelable("product")
        var productDetail = binding.productDetails1
        val currency:Currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
        val symbol = currency.symbol
        binding.price.text = "$symbol ${productDetail?.price}"
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        viewmodel.idsList.add(productDetail?.id)
        val array = viewmodel.idsList
        Log.d("List of ids",array.toString())

        




        // var priceAmount = binding.priceAmount.text.toString().toFloat()

      //  Log.d("PriceAmount", binding.priceAmount.toString())

        // Log.d("ProductTitle", binding.productDetails1.title)
        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener {
            // Log.d("ProductDetail",initialValue.toString())


                if (productDetail == null) return@setOnClickListener
                viewmodel.quantityValue = viewmodel.quantityValue + 1
                //   binding.totalPriceText.text = "Total price"
                binding.quantityText.text = viewmodel.quantityValue.toString()
                //  binding.priceAmount.text =
                //     (productDetail.price * viewmodel.quantityValue).toString()


        }
        binding.addCartButton.setOnClickListener{
            viewmodel.quantityValue = viewmodel.quantityValue + 1
            binding.quantityText.text = viewmodel.quantityValue.toString()
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Item added to cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


        // Log.d("ProductDetail",priceAmount.toString())

        /*  binding.removeButton.setOnClickListener {
              if (quantityValue != 0) {
                  if (productDetail == null) return@setOnClickListener
                  quantityValue = quantityValue - 1
                  binding.quantityText.text = quantityValue.toString()
                  //   binding.priceAmount.text = (priceAmount*quantityValue).toString()
                  binding.priceAmount.text = (productDetail.price * quantityValue).toString()

              }
          } */

        binding.continueButton.setOnClickListener{
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("quantity_text", String.format("%d",viewmodel.quantityValue))
            val cartFragment = CartFragment()
            cartFragment.arguments = bundle


            val ft = fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ft?.replace(R.id.flFragment,cartFragment)
            ft?.addToBackStack("")
            ft?.commit()
            // Create the transaction
            // Create the transaction
        }
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onCreateViewCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()




      //  binding.productDetails = viewModel.products.value!!.get(0)
      //  binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.hide()
        binding.quantityText.text = viewmodel.quantityValue.toString()
       // binding.priceAmount.text = (binding.productDetails1!!.price!! * viewmodel.quantityValue).toString()
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onResumeCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
       // (activity as AppCompatActivity?)!!.supportActionBar!!.show()
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onStopCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onPauseCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onDestroyViewCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Toast.makeText(activity,"onDestroyCalled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }






}
```

And this is my MainViewModel from where I am getting data of quantity value throughout the fragments.

```
package com.example.ecomapp.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.example.ecomapp.data.Repository
import com.example.ecomapp.model.ProductDataModel
import com.example.ecomapp.model.ProductsData
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainViewModel: ViewModel(){

    private val repository = Repository()

    private val _products = MutableLiveData<List<ProductDataModel>>()
    val products:LiveData<List<ProductDataModel>> = _products



    private val _isLoading = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val isLoading = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    private var quantity_value = 0
    var quantityValue = quantity_value

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            delay(3000)
            _isLoading.value = false
        }
        getProducts()

    }
    fun addQuantityValue(): Int? {
        quantity_value = quantityValue + 1
        return quantity_value
    }

   /* fun productPrice(quantity:Int):Float {
        _price.value =


    } */
   private fun getProducts() {
       viewModelScope.launch {
           val data = repository.getProducts()
           _products.postValue(data)
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: Edited my question which includes code.